# How can I get vsftpd version into shell variable?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, stdout, output, vsftpd

I want to get vsftpd version into shell variable. I can get it to console with ease:

```
# vsftpd -version
vsftpd: version 2.2.2
```

Also I can get a lot of other info into variable:

```
# i=`bash --version 2>&1 | head -n1`; echo "=$i=";
=GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)=
```

(please note output is between "=" signs).
This simple way does not work with vsftpd:

```
# i=`vsftpd -version 2>&1`; echo "=$i=";
vsftpd: version 2.2.2
==
```

Please note $i is "" here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly enough, my `vsftpd` writes the versino string to **`stdin`**. So you probably need to do a rather unusual redirection of `stdin` to `stdout`:

```
i=`/usr/sbin/vsftpd -version 0>&1`
```

How to find this out: run it in `strace` (you'll need to do it as root) and check for the string. In my case the log ends like this:

```
$ strace /usr/sbin/vsftpd -version
...
brk(0)                                  = 0x7f835332d000
brk(0x7f835334e000)                     = 0x7f835334e000
write(0, "vsftpd: version 3.0.2\n", 22) = 22
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The first argument to `write()` is the file descriptor (0/1/2 stand for stdin/stdout/stderr respectively).

Answer (score 1):

The command `vsftpd -v` uses stdin so you can't grab the output in the normal way.

I usually just grab the response from the FTP port. I only allow FTP locally anyway.

`echo "bye" | nc localhost 21`