# A program's output seems to be neither stdout nor stderr?

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin, vsftpd, stderr

I got a program `vsftpd` which output doesn't seem to be either stdout or stderr (if that's even possible?)

My terminal output is:

```
~# vsftpd
500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA private key
```

I tried to redirect to a file but I get nothing in the file and the output still goes to the console:

```
~#vsftpd > /tmp/out.txt
500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA private key

~#vsftpd &> /tmp/out.txt
500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA private key

~#vsftpd 2> /tmp/out.txt
500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA private key
```

I'm actually trying to call this program from .Net Core from which I'm not able to get the StdOut/StdErr neither. And .Net Core crashes with `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` unless I enable StdIn-redirect, which I don't understand, I'm not parsing anything to StdIn and I never experienced this before with any other program calls.

Comment: Is this related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56108/how-can-i-get-vsftpd-version-into-shell-variable

Comment: It sure looks like it! Nice found :-)

Comment: Have you tried re-directing stdin?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it write to stdin!
To redirect to StdOut

```
 ~#(vsftpd 0>&1)
 or
 ~#(vsftpd 0>&1)>/tmp/out.txt
```